# Reference a Member by Name instead of ID, in MDX expression

Tags: ssas, mdx

After some unsuccessful Googling, I decided to ask & answer this question.  For some SQL DBAs like me, dealing with MDX is not a daily routine, but more of a "once in a while" thing.  So when a seemingly simple problem comes up, it's nice to have a simple answer.

"How do I reference a Member by its Name (instead of its ID or identifier), in an MDX query?"  E.g. in a STRTOMEMBER or STRTOSET function, or in a WHERE clause line (slicer) ((not to be confused with a SQL WHERE clause!))

Example--

Dimension hierarchy: `[Family Hierarchy]`

Dimensions within said hierarchy, from top to bottom: `Parent`, `Child`

Members of each dimension include (ID, "Name"):

1. `Parent` members:

   - 1, "Mom"
   - 2, "Pop"
2. `Child` members:

   - 3, "Bro"
   - 4, "Sis"

To slice on `Child` member "Bro", I would use the following expression in my WHERE clause:

`[Family Hierarchy].[Child].&[3]`

But I don't want my reporting layer to know/care about what that ID is.  I want to use the **name** "Bro".  How would I do this?

Comment: in SSMS if you connect to SSAS and then open a new MDX script when you drag a member into the script window it will give you the name?

Comment: Yes, and if you hover over the member in the cube-explorer pane, it will show both the ID and name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the ampersand from the last element of the expression and use the name:

`[Family Hierarchy].[Child].[Bro]`

Or in `STRTOMEMBER` usage, `STRTOMEMBER('[Family Hierarchy].[Child].[Bro]')`

Comment: One thing to be aware of - in the client it can sometimes be useful to use the key version - this gives you the freedom that if the caption name is changed in the future your application will still work ok